# Convert SQL Query to Rails ORM Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Whats the eqivalent Rails ORM command for the SQL Query ?

```
select next_refresh_time from yoddle_jobs where account_key = "YzI5ZDUyNWY5NmYwNWFiNjJiYmE1YTk4Y2VkYTBjYTZmOGM5ZTI0NzE2MzU2MzAwMmU2OWU2MzNiYmQ2YTZhMA==" order by id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: `YoddleJob.where(account_key: "YzI5ZDUyNWY5NmYwNWFiNjJiYmE1YTk4Y2VkYTBjYTZmOGM5ZTI0NzE2MzU2MzAwMmU2OWU2MzNiYmQ2YTZhMA==").select('next_refresh_time').limit(1)` try this

Comment: is this query working?

Comment: Its works.. but doesn't choose the latest one - last record.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent query is

```
YoddleJob.select(:next_refresh_time).where(:account_key => "YzI5ZDUyNWY5NmYwNWFiNjJiYmE1YTk4Y2VkYTBjYTZmOGM5ZTI0NzE2MzU2MzAwMmU2OWU2MzNiYmQ‌​2YTZhMA==").last(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
YoddleJob.select(:next_refresh_time).where(account_key: "YzI5ZDUyNWY5NmYwNWFiNjJiYmE1YTk4Y2VkYTBjYTZmOGM5ZTI0NzE2MzU2MzAwMmU2OWU2MzNiYmQ‌​2YTZhMA==").order("id DESC").first
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be like this

```
YoddleJob.where(:account_key => "YzI5ZDUyNWY5NmYwNWFiNjJiYmE1YTk4Y2VkYTBjYTZmOGM5ZTI0NzE2MzU2MzAwMmU2OWU2MzNiYmQ2YTZhMA==").select('next_refresh_time').order("id desc").limit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
YoddleJob.where(account_key: "YzI5ZDUyNWY5NmYwNWFiNjJiYmE1YTk4Y2VkYTBjYTZmOGM5ZTI0NzE2MzU2MzAwMmU2OWU2MzNiYmQ‌​2YTZhMA==").select('next_refresh_time').last(1)
```